# NextAuth - AccessToken not refreshed with MongoDB and Coinbase

Tags: mongodb, next.js, refresh-token, coinbase-api, next-auth

I have a problem with my authentication via Coinbase (using Nextauth) on NextJS app.

I made this code below, and it saves the profile well in my Mongodb database. But when I re-login, accesstoken and refreshtoken are not changed...
So I can’t use the APIs afterwards.

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';


async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    const url =
      "https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token?" +
      new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.COINBASE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.COINBASE_SECRET_ID,
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      })

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      method: "POST",
    })

    const refreshedTokens = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens
    }

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_in * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    }
  }
}


export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        Providers.Coinbase({
            clientId: process.env.COINBASE_CLIENT_ID,      
            clientSecret: process.env.COINBASE_SECRET_ID,  
            callbackUrl: process.env.COINBASE_CALLBACKURL,
            scope: "wallet:accounts:read",
        }),
    ],

    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
            // Initial sign in
            if (account && user) {
                return {
                    accessToken: user.data.access_token,
                    accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + user.data.expires_in * 1000,
                    refreshToken: user.data.refresh_token,
                    user,
                }
            }
        
            // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
            if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
                return token
            }
        
            // Access token has expired, try to update it
            return refreshAccessToken(token)
        },

        async session(session, token) {
          session.accessToken = token.accessToken
          return session
        }
        
    },

    events: {
      async signIn(message) { console.log('success signin') },
      async signOut(message) { console.log('success signout') },
      async createUser(message) { console.log('success user create') },
      async updateUser(message) { console.log('success update user') },
      async session(message) { console.log('success session') },
      async error(message) { console.log('error') }
    },

    // A database is optional, but required to persist accounts in a database
    database: `mongodb+srv://${process.env.NOSQL_USER}:${process.env.NOSQL_PWD}@${process.env.NOSQL_HOST}/${process.env.NOSQL_TABLE}`,
});
```

I’m still a beginner on NextJS and React in particular:) Thanks for your help

Comment: I see no MongoDB interaction.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: The last line of code ends the link with mongodb and the user creation works only for first login

Comment: I have no idea what you mean `The last line of code ends the link with mongodb`.  The variable `database` is just a string.  It does nothing. In fact, you do not have the mongodb dependences imported, so you can't be doing anything with the mongo database in this code.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the save in the database works. It is the reset of the token at re-login that does not work